# How to execute a certain log task for request before using the express json initializer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to execute a certain log task for request before even using the express json initializer.
I have an issue where the nodejs service recieves an invalid json which is caught in express json parser and returned to client without even being logged.
Suggest me a solution where I can sort of add a middleware and log request before it is acknowledged

my code

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    logger.info({
        event: 'request_preprocess',
        msg: 'in app middleware'
    });
    console.log('hi there 678');
    next();
});

app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
```

I tried running the above code but I don't see the console logs

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting 4 parameters `(err, req, res, next)`. This is the default error handling method in express and will only be reached if an unhandled error occurs.

Remove `err` so it's just `(req, res, next)`.

See [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) under "The default error handler".

Comment: It says
Express comes with a built-in error handler that takes care of any errors that might be encountered in the app. This default error-handling middleware function is added at the end of the middleware function stack.

Now how can i add it in start of middleware stack!

Comment: @ShivamBalikondwar All middlewares will be executed in the order they are added. If you want to run it before anything else, just move it further up, just under `const app  = express()`. However, this is still just an error handler, it will only run if a route or middleware returns an error.
If you want to track down your issue and still keep the error handler, i would just add the error handler function after all other middlewares and routers and then create another middleware to log all incoming requests at the top without the `err` parameter to make sure it runs on EVERY request.

Comment: I just checked after implementing it, it seems to work as middleware but my use case is different
I have a websocket server that I initialise in my app and have routes elsewhere
So the calls to my websocket server fail to call this middleware (i fixed the error handler part)